# PHP Count Number of Times A String Appears As A Value Inside An Array

Tags: php, arrays, search, count

So I looked around here for a bit but cant seem to get this right, so I am forced to make a new post. I gave it an effort! Don't hurt me.

**Sample Array:**

```
$ndata = Array
(
    [ARMOR_HEAD] => Andariel's Visage
    [ARMOR_TORSO] => Blackthorne's Surcoat
    [ARMOR_FEET] => Illusory Boots
    [ARMOR_HANDS] => Gauntlets of Akkhan
    [ARMOR_SHOULDERS] => Pauldrons of Akkhan
    [ARMOR_LEGS] => Blackthorne's Jousting Mail
    [ARMOR_BRACERS] => Nemesis Bracers
    [ARMOR_MAINHAND] => Gyrfalcon's Foote
    [ARMOR_OFFHAND] => Jekangbord
    [ARMOR_WAIST] => Blackthorne's Notched Belt
    [ARMOR_RRING] => Ring of Royal Grandeur
    [ARMOR_LRING] => Stone of Jordan
    [ARMOR_NECK] => Kymbo's Gold
)

  $count = count(preg_grep('Akkhan', $ndata));
  print_r($count);
```

So this is only returns 1 instead of 2. I also tried `array_search()`, but that simply returns a the first found with its key. Or `in_array` but that is just boolean I guess.. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `preg_grep` is not a string, it is a regular expression pattern represented as a string. Try this:

```
preg_grep('/Akkhan/i', $ndata)
```

For more information, see the documentation page for [preg_grep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php).

Comment: Thanks. Where can I find information on those patterns so I know what is going on there? Edit: Ah nice edit thanks again